# Content in part of the text

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I often come across a situation where I need to check if there is a piece of text in a sentence or paragraph.
For clarity, we present such a code

```
MyText = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[starts-with(@id, "popover-")]')
for list_MyText in MyText:
    print(list_MyText.text)
```

I get 5 different sentences of 10 words. And I need to check, for example, that in each of the 5 sentences there is the word "Hello". What ways can this be implemented?

Comment: How is _checking each of the 5 sentences there is the word "Hello"_ related to _Selenium_? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it as following code :

```
for list_MyText in MyText:
   if 'Hello' in list_MyText.text
```

Comment: Everything turned out to be so simple .. Thank you, I thought it would be more difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go to count the presence of your words.

```
MyText = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[starts-with(@id, "popover-")]')
count=0
for list_MyText in MyText:
    print(list_MyText.text)
    if "Hello" in list_MyText.text:
       count=+1
print(count)
```

Answer (score -1):

A simpler way to do this is to just build the criteria into the locator. That way you don't have to loop through each element and see if it contains the desired string, e.g.

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[starts-with(@id, "popover-")][contains(.,'Hello')]')
```

Now with that, if you expect 3 of these elements on the page, you can assert that there are three.

```
list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[starts-with(@id, "popover-")][contains(.,'Hello')]')
assertEqual(3, len(list))
```

See [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertEqual) for more info on this and other asserts.